# Windows Phone HtmlAgilityPack fails getting node from specified class

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I have been stuck for now a long time on this one. I have this HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/samplepath/" class="sample_model">Test</a>
```

And I am using the following C# code to retrieve the node

```
var imagediv = (from imgnode in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                where imgnode.Name == "a" &&
                                imgnode.Attributes["class"].Value == "sample_model"
                                select imgnode).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I debug and step into this code, it goes out of scope. I don't get what I want, nor do I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var imagediv = (from imgnode in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                where imgnode.Attributes["class"].Value == "sample_model"
                select imgnode).FirstOrDefault();
```

or simply

```
var imagediv = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='sample_model']");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't. With the first piece of code, it goes of of scope. (It doesn't step through the code below, but jumps to the next curly brace). The second piece of code, VS says HtmlAgilityPack doesn't contain a definition for SelectSingleNode. I am using HtmlAgilityPack for WP V1.4.5.0

Comment: @user1576422 I tested before posting and above code returns the `a` tag. (I don't know `SelectSingleNode` may not exist in HAP for WP)